# Tuple to table from counting DNA sequences

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I want to count the number of bases in a DNA sequence, return the counts of each type of base in the sequence, and also print out a two column table where the first column is the base and the second column is the associated base count. I can get the function to return the base count but I am not sure how to print the table. I would like to do this analysis with base python functions although I assume it would be easier to do with some python module.

Code:

```
 def base_counter(DNA):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    G = 0
    C = 0
    for base in DNA:
        if base == "A":
            A = A + 1
        elif base == "T":
            T = T + 1
        elif base == "G":
            G = G + 1
        elif base == "C":
            C = C + 1
        else:
            pass
    return A,T,G,C
```

Parameter input:

```
dna="AAGCTACGTGGGTGACTTT"
```

Function call:

```
counts=base_counter(dna)
print(counts)
```

Output:

```
(4, 6, 6, 3)
```

Desired output:

```
print(counts)
  A   4
  T   6
  G   6
  C   3
```

and

```
counts
(4, 6, 6, 3)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from within the function:

```
out_str="A    "+str(A)+"\n"+\
      "T    "+str(T)+"\n"+\
      "G    "+str(G)+"\n"+\
      "C    "+str(C)
return out_str
```

now you can call and print it and it will be printed in your desired format:

```
result=base_counter(DNA)
print(result)
```

for OP's request full code:

```
def base_counter(DNA):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    G = 0
    C = 0
    for base in DNA:
        if base == "A":
            A = A + 1
        elif base == "T":
            T = T + 1
        elif base == "G":
            G = G + 1
        elif base == "C":
            C = C + 1
    out_str = "A    " + str(A) + "\n"+\
    "T    " + str(T) + "\n"+\
    "G    " + str(G) + "\n"+\
    "C    " + str(C)
    return out_str

base=base_counter("AAGCTACGTGGGTGACTTT")
print(base)
```

output:

```
A    4
T    6
G    6
C    3
```

Comment: I want to be able to do this: counts=base_counter(dna)
print (counts) and not have it print within the function

Answer (score 2):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the bases and `pandas` to set the data in a column-wise manner. Here is an example

```
from collections import Counter
import pandas as pd

# Count the bases
dna="AAGCTACGTGGGTGACTTT"
count = Counter(dna)
tup = ()
for _, value in sorted(count.items()):
  tup += (value,)
print(tup  # Outputs (4, 3, 6, 6)

# Set it in a pandas dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(list(dict(count).items()), columns=['Base', 'Count'])
print(df.to_string(index=False))
# Output
# Base  Count
#   A      4
#   G      6
#   C      3
#   T      6
```

Answer (score 1):

1) you have a bug - your `return` is indented one extra tab to the right

2) use a `dict`:

```
def base_counter(DNA):
    dna_dict = {
        "A": 0,
        "T": 0,
        "G": 0,
        "C": 0,
    }
    for base in DNA:
        if base == "A":
            dna_dict["A"] += 1
        elif base == "T":
            dna_dict["T"] += 1
        elif base == "G":
            dna_dict["G"] += 1
        elif base == "C":
            dna_dict["C"] += 1
    return dna_dict


dna = "AAGCTACGTGGGTGACTTT"

counts = base_counter(dna)
for base, count in counts.items():
    print(base, count)
```

but if you have to keep the function as is:

```
def base_counter(DNA):
    A = 0
    T = 0
    G = 0
    C = 0
    for base in DNA:
        if base == "A":
            A = A + 1
        elif base == "T":
            T = T + 1
        elif base == "G":
            G = G + 1
        elif base == "C":
            C = C + 1
    return A,T,G,C


dna = "AAGCTACGTGGGTGACTTT"

counts = base_counter(dna)
for base, count in zip("ATGC", counts):
    print(base, count)
```

Comment: The output has to be as shown in my post (i.e. (4, 6, 6, 3) and not {'A': 4, 'T': 6, 'G': 6, 'C': 3})

Comment: so, keep your function as is (just don't forget to unindent the `return`, and replace the function call code snippet with this:
    `counts = base_counter(dna);
    for base, count in zip("ATGC", counts):
        print(base, count)`

Comment: can you please update your answer with this solution?

Comment: You can omit the `if`s in your dictionary approach (which I would prefer) by using the simpler `for base in DNA: dna_dict[base] += 1`. It's at the cost of not being able to handle invalid characters, but it would work for the OP. (Although adding an error handler should be easy, too.)

Answer (score 0):

you can make another function for printing the results:

```
def print_bases(bases):
print("A    "+str(bases[0])+"\n"
  "T    "+str(bases[1])+"\n"
  "G    "+str(bases[2])+"\n"
  "C    "+str(bases[3]))
print_bases(counts)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it in the same function such that the function returns the tuple ((4, 6, 6, 3)) after running base_counter(dna) and then is able to print the table by print(counts))? So basically the opposite output of your first solution. Your first solution returns the table and prints the tuple.

Comment: from the first solution take you can return a string (exactly whats written in the print function) and then when you call the function it will return a string, which you will be able to print with print() function

Comment: should i ask a new question? hard to understand without an example of what you just mentioned.

Comment: you could either implement it by returning the counters and making an extra function to print them like I showed you here, or return the reaults as a string, already formatted as above, like I did in my EDITED original answer, and you can print that directly, Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm getting an indent error and it is only printing A   4 from the table